# What would be the reaction if melting iron is put in normal water?

Tags: water, metal

What would be the reaction if melting iron is put in normal water? Will water be chemically changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the other metals we usually see in the reactivity series, such as calcium, magnesium, zinc, etc., hot iron does not form iron hydroxide, instead it forms iron oxide. The reaction is:

$\ce{3Fe + 4H2O <=> FeO.Fe2O3 + 4H2}$

Iron is similar to magnesium and zinc as they react only with hot water (not cold water). But the reaction of iron with hot water is less vigorous than that of magnesium and zinc.